# Ruby - rescue multiple assignments from a parsed XML

Tags: ruby

I've parsed some XML using Nokogiri like such:

`doc = Nokogiri::XML(payload)`

Now I've created an object to which I am assigning some attributes using that parsed XML.

If for whatever reason data was missing or the XML was not parsed correctly I want to provide me an appropriate message. I've done this:

```
fm = BigMessage.new

begin
  fm.title = doc.children.at('title').child.content
  fm.languagecode = doc.children.at('language').child.content
  fm.description = doc.children.at('description').child.content
rescue => e
  log_err("Could not update - reason #{e}")
end
```

However - the error simply shows `Uncaught exception`. Is it possible to say error due to `assigning fm.title with null`?

And is this actually the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the actual error message which you can get via `e.message` so your log line would look like:

`log_err("Could not update - reason #{e.message}")`

That being said - the message still wont have contextual data like you're asking for.

To get more contextual data you'd have attempt to read/set each property on its own, then if that failed you'd know what the failing property is.

To do this it might be something like this pseudo-code:

```
fm = BigMessage.new

properties = [:title, :language, :description]

properties.each do |property|
  begin
    value = doc.children.at(property.to_s).child.content
    fm.send(:"#{property}=", value)
  rescue => ex
    log_err("Could not update property:#{property} - reason #{e.message}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Great - that looks good. However say I had a case where one of the object attributes say `fm.customerlist = someArray`. I guess I'd have to place that in its own rescue block?

Comment: Also the properties name could change so I could end up with: `fm.description = doc.children.at('descriptionSong').child.content`

Comment: I ended making properties look like: `properties = ["title" => "title", "language" => "language", "description" => "descriptionSong"]`. What do you think/any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't look at the error message for that. Look at the `backtrace` of the error. Then, you would be able to tell in which line it failed.